# Change Website Content with PHP and AJAX Without Page Reload

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

A server process changes the content of a file readme.txt which is located in a users home directory (Linux Ubuntu 20.04 Server). I want to reflect the file content on the page without fully reloading the site. Therefore I tried AJAX in the `index.php` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Read a File</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<?php
  $reader = file_get_contents("/userhome/readme.txt");
  echo $reader;
?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function readFile() { 
    $.get("index.php"); 
    return false; 
} 
</script>
  
<button onclick="readFile()">Click me</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Shouldn't an AJAX GET request to the PHP file itself load the new content and display it on the page?

Comment: "*Shouldn't an AJAX GET request to the PHP file itself load the new content and display it on the page?*" Not quite - how exactly did you reach this conclusion? Can you provide a source on which you're basing this knowledge? What you're doing here is using the jQuery `$.get()` function to retrieve the contents of `index.php`, but you're not doing anything with the result of said request.

Comment: `$.get("index.php");` just makes the request, you didn't tell it to do anything with it. Please view the examples on the documentation: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Oh, good point! I thought that making the GET request executes the PHP script again, which on the other hand would echo the file content again. Like, when you browse to the site, you are actually making a GET request as well. Then, I may need to rephrase my question: How can I achieve what I intended to do? Read a file and display it's content without reloading the page?

Comment: if you only using `$.get`, from jquery, you might as well use [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

Comment: also `~/` wont be `/home/userhome`

Comment: What would be the benefit of fetch over get? And you are right, fixed. I initially wanted to indicate the user home...but then messed it up by writing it down and using ~. Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript can't access anything that is not reachable through a browser. Do as follows: 1) Expose readme.txt to the public, 2) Send a fetch request to it, 3) Read the response as txt, 4) Set the text content of an element to what you received from the fetch

Comment: Thanks Slava! If that is the only way, I will do it like that. I just wanted to know if there is a way to do it like I tried above :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**reader.php**

```
<?php
  $reader = file_get_contents("/userhome/readme.txt");
  echo $reader;
?>
```

So basically after clicking the Read me button, the div with id `read` will be filled with the txt content

**index.php**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Read a File</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    

    <div id="read">

</div>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#load").click(function(){
        $("#read").load("reader.php");
      });
    });
    </script>
      
    <button id="load">Read me</button>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

there are many other solutions for this